# Javascript (NodeJS) promise pending?

Tags: javascript, node.js

```
function  f () {
   return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        resolve(4);
    })
}

function  g () {
    return f().then((res) => {return res;})

}

console.log(g());
```

**This returns** `Promise { <pending> }`

If I returned `res`(in the then) and then returned `f()`, why isn't the output **4**?

Comment: If it is to return 4, how would you chain `then`s?

Comment: @WiktorZychla?  In `return f().then((res) => {return res;})`, does this give `4`? Since the `then` returns 4??

Comment: Then doesn't return 4, it returns a Promise. The function you pass as argument to then returns 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I access previous promise results in a .then() chain?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28250680/how-do-i-access-previous-promise-results-in-a-then-chain)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

a valid answer would be:

```
function f() {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

        resolve(4);
    })
}

function g() {
    return f().then((res) => {
        return res;
    })
    .then((res) =>{
        console.log(res);
    })

}
g()
```

Why? Any time you `return` from inside a `then` statement in a promise, it passes it to the next statement (then or catch). Try commenting out `return res` and you'll see that it prints `undefined`.

==============
However, with ES7 we can use `async/await`. We can replicate the above using the following code:

```
function f() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve(4);
  });
}

async function g() {
  var a = await f();
  // do something with a ...
  console.log(a);
}

g();
```

It's important to note that `console.log(g())` still returns a promise. This is because in the actual function `g`, resolving the promise gets delayed and therefore doesn't block the rest of our code from executing but the function body can utilize the returned value from `f`.

NOTE: to run this you need node 7 and it should be executed with the `--harmony-async-await` option.

===========
EDIT to include new code snippet
Look at the following code. You must use then to access the previous objects - however, where you access it in this case is up to you. You can call then on each promise inside of `Promise.all`, in this case `.then((userVictories) => ...).then(...)` or once `Promise.all` returns. It's important to note that Promise.all returns once **all** promises it contains resolve.

```
var membersArray = groupFound.members;
Promise.all(membersArray.map((member) => {
  return db.doneTodo.find({ 'victor._id': member._id }).then((userVictories) => {
    return {
      email: member.email,
      victories: userVictories.length,
    }
  }).then(obj => {
    /*
        obj is each object with the signature:
            {email: '', victories: ''}

            calling this then is optional if you want to process each object
            returned from '.then((userVictories) =>)'

            NOTE: this statement is processed then *this* promise resolves

            We can send an email to each user with an update
     */
  });
}))
  .then((arr) => {
    /*
        arr is an array of all previous promises in this case:
        [{email: '', victories: ''}, {email: '', victories: ''}, ...]

        NOTE: this statement is processed when all of the promises above resolve.

        We can use the array to get the sum of all victories or the 
        user with the most victories
     */
  })
```

Comment: But here: `var membersArray = groupFound.members;
            Promise.all(membersArray.map((member) => {
                return db
                    .doneTodo
                    .find({'victor._id': member._id})
                    .then((userVictories) => {
                        return {
                            email: member.email,
                            victories: userVictories.length
                        }
                    });
            }))`  We didn't need to attach a "then" in front of the object?

Comment: 'We didn't need to attach a "then" in front of the object?', Which object? `db.doneTodo.find` returns a promise after which you call `.then((userVictories) => ...`. I don't fully understand your comment

Comment: The last object with "email" and "victories..."

Comment: `membersArray` I'm assuming is an array of objects which have an email and id property (`{email: 'test@test.com', id:1}`). By calling map, you iterate over each member and call `db.doneTodo.find` which resolves a promise. Inside of your then block `.then((userVictories) => ...)` you handle its result. Promise.all will return once all promises in the array resolve and thus it ends up being an array of objects `{email: ..., victories: ...}`. In order to access these objects you need to call then like so `Promise.all(...).then(arr => console.log(res);)`

Comment: Do `var a = Promise.all(...)` and `console.log(a)` it should print a promise

Comment: Yes, I see that, but my point was, since we are returning `{ return { email: member.email, victories: userVictories.length }` inside a `then`, dont we need another then after this FOR this object?

Comment: I see, no unless you want to process `{ email: member.email, victories: userVictories.length }` further. But again, if you want to access the results you need to use `Promise.all(...).then(/* [{email: 'test', victories:1}]'*/)`

Comment: I thought you said that we needed another "then" if we use return inside a previous "then?"

Comment: No. When calling `return` inside of a then statement, the value returned from the first `then` is available inside the next `then` statement. Therefore in order to access the values from the previous `then`, you need to process them inside of the next `then` - they are not accessible otherwise. You cannot return from a then method and have the value returned available outside of it (you **initial** question). Hence my answer above 'I see, no unless you want to process { email: member.email, victories: userVictories.length } further. '. The second code snippet is different from the initial one.

Comment: Look at my second answer `Promise.all(/* your code */).then(...)` This is where you would normally call the then statement to access the results of Promise.all. Yes - you do need to use `then` to access the results of a promise (unless you use async/await), but in your second example it should be after `Promise.all`.

Comment: But how does using return {email: ... id: .....} replace the old item inside the array? We used return, but I dont get how it replaces the item with map

Comment: The returned array after calling map is an array of promises. Calling `return db.doneTodo .find(...)` returns a promise for each entry in the `membersArray`. Each Promise in the array resolves to `{email: ... id: .....}`. Look at my edited answer

Comment: I see that it resolves to `return {email: ... id: .....}`, but then what happens? Can you use return... to replace the item using map? Wouldn't you get promise pending or undefined?

Comment: do you mean have the function passed to map return `{email: ... id: .....}` rather than a promise? No, but Promise.all does that for you. It ensures that instead of an array of promises, you get an array of results from each promise in the array passed to Promise.all

Comment: Yes, we passed `{email: ... id: .....}` to map rather than a promise? So Map does that for us?

Comment: Also, what was the use of return db...?

Comment: We can't simply return `{email:..., id:...}` and have it accessible from outside the promise - we need to resolve it in order to get the result. `db.doneTodo.find` is a promise so `return db.doneTodo.find` returns a promise. `membersArray.map(...)` results in `[Promise, Promise, Promise, ...]`. Promise.all resolves each promise in an array its passed (e.g. `Promise.all([Promise, Promise, Promise])` and makes their results available to a `then` statement called **after** `Promise.all`

Comment: What would happen without the "return?"

Comment: we would get an array of undefined . Its like `console.log([1,2,3].map(val => {val + 1}))` vs `console.log([1,2,3].map(val => { return val + 1}))` one is `[ 2, 3, 4 ]` the other is `[ undefined, undefined, undefined ]`

Comment: Try playing with this code `var membersArray = [
  {
    _id: 1,
    email: '1',
  },
  {
    _id: 2,
    email: 2,
  },
];
Promise.all(membersArray.map((member) => {
  return Promise.resolve([
    ...Array(Math.round(Math.random() * 20)).keys(),
  ])
    .then((userVictories) => {
      return {
        email: member.email,
        victories: userVictories.length,
      }
    });
})).then(res => console.log(res));` as its very similar to what your asking about

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at **jQuery** first as an introduction to learning promises.

What does this code return? What is the value of `result`?

```
var result = $('body');
```

Hint: It won't be the `<body/>` body HTML element.

`result` is a *jQuery collection object*. Internally it holds a reference to the body tag. But the actual `result` object is a collection.

What does this return?

```
var result = $('body').css('background', 'red');
```

Again, it returns a jQuery collection.

And this?

```
var result = $('body').css('background', 'red').animate({height: "20px"});
```

Same thing. A jQuery collection.

Now, what does this **promise based code** return?

```
var result = new Promise();
```

It's probably clear this returns a promise. But what about this code?

```
var result = new Promise().resolve().then(() => {
    return 'Hello';
});
```

What is the value of `result` now? Hint: It's not the string `'Hello'`.

It's a promise!

What does this return?

```
var result = new Promise().resolve().then(() => {
    return new Promise().resolve();
}).then(() => {
    return 'Hello';
}).catch(() => {
    console.log('Something went wrong');
});
```

It returns a promise! Promises let us access values in functions that are called at later times. Until the function is executed, you won't have access to whatever the promise "returns," or "resolves" with. Once you enter a promise chain, you always have to use `.then(fn)` to handle the next step in the program flow.

Javascript is **asynchronous**. All top level code is executed in order without pausing. The promise resolves at a later time, long after your `console.log` has finished executing. To get values back, you need to stay in promise chain land:

```
g().then( result => console.log(result) );
```

Comment: Thanks! What happens here though: `Promise.all(membersArray.map((member) => {
                return db   ///NEED THE RETURN HERE
                    .doneTodo
                    .find({'victor._id': member._id})
                    .then((userVictories) => {
                        return {
                            email: member.email,
                            victories: userVictories.length
                        }
                    });
            })).then( (res) => console.log(res)) ` ?

Comment: There is nothing after `{ return { email: member.email, victories: userVictories.length }`

Comment: The chained `.then()` after a Promise.all will be an array holding the values of each resolved promise https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Comment: Your code looks fine on on the surface. Try adding a catch at the end to see if an error is getting eaten https://gist.github.com/AndrewRayCode/6495e7c0dc0f2370184c90ead7a528ea

Comment: How does one resolve a promise? Does `{ return { email: member.email, victories: userVictories.length }` resolve the promise?

Comment: yes returning inside a promise will make the next `.then()` get the value of that return

Comment: But we dont have a then(), and the next then, takes the whole array (the res)