# Async console log works but res => {return res} does not

Tags: node.js, express, asynchronous, promise, async-await

I have been trying to read up on how asynchronicity works and what promises are, but still not grasping the concept properly.

I understand that asynchronous function returns a promise but at the same time it can return content from an api in my case.

```
let username = list_scores[i].score.username;

      ///Await Hiscores fetches json from api.
      ///Hiscores connects to third party api and fetches data dependant on (name)

      async function getUserAsync() {
        async function getHS (name) {
          var response = await Hiscores.fetch(name).catch(console.error)
          var result = JSON.stringify(response);
          // var resultparse = JSON.parse(result)
          return result;
        }
       return getHS(username).then(result => JSON.parse(result)).catch(console.error);
      }

      let hs = getUserAsync().then(console.log)
```

In the above example json fetched in var response shows up in the console as intended but when I change it to try and make it return the same log as a variable

```
      let hs = getUserAsync().then(res => {return res;}).catch(console.error)
      console.log(hs)
```

It returns

```
Promise { <pending> }
```

Kind of at a loss here , been googling for few days now....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript (NodeJS) promise pending?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41411142/javascript-nodejs-promise-pending)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

so `hs` is an unfulfilled promise. if you were in an `async` function, you could `await` the response from `getUserAsync()`, but it doesnt look like you are; hence you need to handle it the old fashioned Promise way

```
let username = list_scores[i].score.username;
getUserAsync(username).then(user => {
    //handle user
})

///Await Hiscores fetches json from api.
///Hiscores connects to third party api and fetches data dependant on (name)

async function getHS(name) {
    var response = await Hiscores.fetch(name).catch(console.error)
    var result = JSON.stringify(response);
    // var resultparse = JSON.parse(result)
    return result;
}

async function getUserAsync(username) {
    return getHS(username).then(result => JSON.parse(result)).catch(console.error);
}
```

Comment: That was indeed it. I had been swapping around every line trying to find out when it stops sending pending but it was a different approach all along that I couldn't grasp. Thank you kind stranger.